# How to access Ubuntu files from another Ubuntu installation on the same PC

Tags: boot

To be quick. I had windows 7 and Ubuntu.

I installed a new windows 7 copy and now it doesn't show ubuntu on windows boot manager.

I need to access to the files on ubuntu.

I tried to install ext2explore etc. but I have had so many problems with the installations.

I wonder if I should just run another Ubuntu from live cd and somehow access to the old Ubuntu files from there, or is there another way?

---EDIT---
I can see my files from Live CD but can't do anything with them. I'm trying to follow this guide http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/ but when i write in terminal 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub

it says command not found

Comment: Please explain the situation clearly. You can fix grub loader and regain access to Ubuntu or you want to play with files on ubuntu from Windows. Which one is your target?

Comment: I want to fix grub loader. I am at the point with LIVE CD trying with commands from link howtogeek.com but when i type sudo grub it says command not found

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would work. If you load up the Ubuntu installation on a CD/USB you can view every file on your computer. Using this it should show your old Ubuntu files if you look in the right place.

Or you could try and reinstll the grub menu This should show you how:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (2nd Option on this page) with live cd to repair. But not use recommended repair. Click advanced settings and install GRUB to the beginning of your hard disk (eg.: sda)
After finished repair process, restart and also think to paste your paste-bin link here.